# How to use SharedPreference Globally?

Tags: flutter, dart

I pass the value of both userProfileID And ,userstype to Profilepage() as shown below but when i go to profile page and I try to print the value of both this variable I will get Null value, I think they Actually not passed from this _HomePageState, anyone help?

```
     Here is Where I pass the Value of both 
    userProfileID as a UserID and userstype as UserTypes inside initState() below, 
    and both  UserID and UserTypes are Obtained from SharedPrefrence
 (I call GetData to obtain the value of  UserID and UserTypes from SharedPreference )
        
          class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
         
              String UserID;
              String UserTypes;
              List<Widget>_children;
              bool isSignedIn= false;
              int _CurrentIndex=0;
            
              void initState(){
            
                    super.initState();
                       GetData();
            
                _children=[
                  TimeLinePage(UsersIdTimeline:UserID,UsersTypeTimeline:UserTypes),
                  SearchPage(searchUserSID: UserID,searchUsertype:UserTypes), //search(),
                  UploadPage(uploadUserSID:UserID,uploadUsertype:   UserTypes),
                  NotificationsPage(NotifyUserSID: UserID,NotifyUsertype:UserTypes),
                  ProfilePage(userProfileID:UserID,userstype:UserTypes),
                ];
               
                  if(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!=null){
                    setState(() {
                      isSignedIn= true;
                    });
                  }else{
                    setState(() {
                      isSignedIn= false;
                       });
                  }
              }
              @override
              Widget build(BuildContext context) {
              if(isSignedIn){
               return buildHomeScreen();
            
             } else{
               return buildSignedInScreen();
             }
              }
             void GetData()async {
                SharedPreferences preferences= await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
                setState(() {
                   UserID=preferences.get('UserId');
                 UserTypes=preferences.get('UserType');
            
                });
              }
        
        }
```

---

```
    here is buildHomeScreen
    
   class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  // ignore: non_constant_identifier_names
  String UserID;
  String UserTypes;
  List<Widget>_children;
  List<Widget>_agentchildren;
  bool isSignedIn= false;
  // ignore: non_constant_identifier_names
  int _CurrentIndex=0;
  int _agentCurrentIndex=0;

  void initState(){
  
        super.initState();
           GetData();

    _children=[
      TimeLinePage(UsersIdTimeline:UserID,UsersTypeTimeline:UserTypes),
      SearchPage(searchUserSID: UserID,searchUsertype:UserTypes), 
      UploadPage(uploadUserSID:UserID,uploadUsertype:UserTypes),
      NotificationsPage(NotifyUserSID: UserID,NotifyUsertype:UserTypes),
      ProfilePage(userProfileID:UserID,userstype:UserTypes),
    ];
  
      if(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!=null){
        setState(() {
          isSignedIn= true;
        });
      }else{
        setState(() {
          isSignedIn= false;
           });
      }
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  if(isSignedIn){
 if(UserTypes=='agent'){
   return buildagentScreen();

 } else if(UserTypes== 'Signupuser'||
     UserTypes==  'owner'||
     UserTypes==  'seller'
    ){
   return buildHomeScreen();
     }else{
   return buildSignedInScreen();
 }

  }
  }
```

---

Here is My ProfilePage(), if I try to get the value of both
(  String userstype; String userProfileID;) in this page
i get Null value but I alredy pass the value of them from the above _HomePageState()

```
 class ProfilePage extends StatefulWidget {
            String userstype;
            String userProfileID;
           ProfilePage({this.userProfileID, this.userstype});
          @override
          _ProfilePageState createState() => _ProfilePageState();
        }
        class _ProfilePageState extends State<ProfilePage> {
          final String CurrentOnlineUserID=curentuser?.uid;
          bool loading =false;
          int countPost=0;
          String postOrientation="grid";
          List<Post> PostList=[];
          void initState(){
            getAllProfilePost();
          }
        
          @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        
            return Scaffold(
              backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                appBar:header(context,strTitle:"profile"),
                body:ListView(
                    children:<Widget>[
              TopView(),
                    ]
                ),
            );
          }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use shared preferences globally for your application.

import 'dart:async' show Future;
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

```
class PreferenceUtils {
  static Future<SharedPreferences> get _instance async => _prefsInstance ??= await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  static SharedPreferences _prefsInstance;

  // call this method from iniState() function of mainApp().
  static Future<SharedPreferences> init() async {
    _prefsInstance = await _instance;
    return _prefsInstance;
  }

  static String getString(String key, [String defValue]) {
    return _prefsInstance.getString(key) ?? defValue ?? "";
  }

  static Future<bool> setString(String key, String value) async {
    var prefs = await _instance;
    return prefs?.setString(key, value) ?? Future.value(false);
  }
}
```

Please follow this link
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61046061/8218866

Answer (score 0):

When the `_HomePageState`  is created, the `initState` is called, and so this line:

```
_children=[
                  [...],
                  ProfilePage(userProfileID:UserID,userstype:UserTypes),
                ];
```

This line is *creating* the object of a `ProfilePage` with the desired UserID's and UserTypes. This `ProfilePage` object will be put inside the `_children` list.

When you do this:

```
setState(() {
                 UserID=preferences.get('UserId');
                 UserTypes=preferences.get('UserType');
            
                });
```

You are 1) calling the build method again, and 2) updating the value of UserID and UserTypes. You did **not** change the value of any itens inside the `_childrens` list. Or the list itself. Hence the misbehavior you noticed.

There are many ways to solve this, but the essence would be to move this list declaration inside the build method. An example:

```
@override
              Widget build(BuildContext context) {
              _children = [.....]
              if(isSignedIn){
                  [...]
```

Doing this way would not be a *pretty* way to do it, because you are creating lots of new (and useless) objets every time the build method is called. Maybe in a small application this wouldn't be a problem, and for didactic reasons I chose to show this way in this answer.

The more correct way would be to :

- Switch and instantiate inside `buildHomeScreen` the body object:

```
Scaffold buildHomeScreen(){
    Widget body;
    switch (_currentIndex) {
        case 0:
          body = 
    TimeLinePage(UsersIdTimeline:UserID,UsersTypeTimeline:UserTypes);
          break;
        case 1: 
          body = ...;
          break;
      }


    return Scaffold(
           ...
            body: body,
           ...

    )
}
```

Which should give you the same result.

Comment: I Updated my home page Please Correct my code! I don't clearly  understand how i correct it,  what i want is to pass  the value of   userProfileID and ,userstype  from _homepageState,

Comment: I use setState() in order to set The value of  UserID's and UserTypes  from SharedPreference, because  initially  UserID's and UserTypesare null

Comment: I use setState() in order to set The value of  UserID's and UserTypes  from SharedPreference, because  initially  UserID's and UserTypesare null and also i call SetState() method before creating the object of a ProfilePage with the desired UserID's and UserTypes

Comment: I create a global SharedPreference class please can you give me a hint how I use it inside my code, for example how I pass it  to profile page() from _homePageState()

Comment: Thank''s a Lot Everything forks for me. you are Smart,