# shared preferences does not save radio button checkmark in Flutter

Tags: flutter, radio-button, sharedpreferences, preferences

I implemented the shared preferences package in my Flutter app, with a list widget as radio button, that only save the language preference and not the checkmark.
So when i close the Language screen and come back, the language checkmark goes the the default one even if the language, saved in shared preferences is French or Italian.

**This is my Language screen:**

```
class LanguagesScreen extends StatefulWidget {
const LanguagesScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
State<LanguagesScreen> createState() => _LanguagesScreenState();
}

class Item {
 final String prefix;
 final String? helper;
 const Item({required this.prefix, this.helper});
}

var items = [
   Item(prefix: 'English', helper: 'English',), //value: 'English'
   Item(prefix: 'Français', helper: 'French'),
   Item(prefix: 'Italiano', helper: 'Italian'),
  ];

  class _LanguagesScreenState extends State<LanguagesScreen> {

  var _selectedIndex = 0;
  final _userPref = UserPreferences();
  var _selecLangIndex;

  int index = 0;
  final List<String> entries = <String>['English', 'French', 'Italian'];*/

  //init shared preferences
  @override
  void initState() {
   super .initState();
   _populateField();
  }

 void _populateField() async {
  var prefSettings = await _userPref.getPrefSettings();
  setState((){
    _selecLangIndex = prefSettings.language;
  });
 }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(...
      ),
      body: CupertinoPageScaffold(
        child: Container(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: CupertinoFormSection.insetGrouped(
                    children: [
                      ...List.generate(items.length, (index) => GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () async {
                            setState(() => _selectedIndex = index);
                            if (index == 0){
                              await context.setLocale(Locale('en','US'));
                              _selecIndex = Language.English;
                            }
                            else if (index == 1){
                              await context.setLocale(Locale('fr','FR'));
                              _selecIndex = Language.French;

                            }
                          child: buildCupertinoFormRow(
                            items[index].prefix,
                            items[index].helper,
                            selected: _selectedIndex == index,
                          )
                      )),
                      TextButton(onPressed:
                        _saveSettings,
                        child: Text('save', 
                      )

  buildCupertinoFormRow(String prefix, String? helper, {bool selected = false,}) {
    return CupertinoFormRow(
        prefix: Text(prefix),
        helper: helper != null
        ? Text(helper, style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodySmall,)
            :null, child: selected ? const Icon(CupertinoIcons.check_mark,
      color: Colors.blue, size: 20,) :Container(),
    );
  }

  void _saveSettings() {
    final newSettings = PrefSettings(language:_selecIndex);
    _userPref.saveSettings(newSettings);
    Navigator.pop(context);
  }
}
```

**this is the UserPreference:**

```
   class UserPreferences {
   Future saveSettings(PrefSettings prefSettings) async {
    final preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    await preferences.setInt('language' , prefSettings.language.index );
  }

  Future<PrefSettings> getPrefSettings() async {
    final preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    final language = Language.values[preferences.getInt('language') ?? 0 ];

    return PrefSettings(language: language);
  }
}
```

---

```
enum Language { English, French, Italian}

class PrefSettings{
  final Language language;

  PrefSettings (
      {required this.language});
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm betting that the issue is in `initState`. You are calling `_populateField`, but it doesn't complete before building because it's an `async` method, and you can't `await` for it: so the widget gets build, loading the default position for the checkmark, and only after that `_populateField` completes...but then it's too late to show the saved data correctly.

In my experience, if I have not already instantiated a `SharedPreferences` object somewhere else in the code, I use this to load it:

```
class _LanguagesScreenState extends State<LanguagesScreen> {

[...]

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
        //you can put any async method here, just be 
        //sure that you use the type it returns later when using 'snapshot.data as T'
        future: await SharedPreferences.getInstance(), 
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          //error handling
          if (!snapshot.hasData || snapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.done) {
            return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Center(child: Text(snapshot.error.toString()));
          }
          var prefs= snapshot.data as SharedPreferences;
          //now you have all the preferences available without need to await for them
          return Scaffold((
             [...]
          );
```

EDIT

I started writing another comment, but there are so many options here that there wasn't enough space.

First, the code I posted should go in your `_LanguagesScreenState` build method. The `FutureBuilder` I suggested should wrap anything that depends on the Future you must wait for to complete. I put it up at the root, above `Scaffold`, but you can move it down the widgets' tree as you need, just remember that everything that needs to read the preferences has to be inside the `FutureBuilder`.

Second, regarding `SharedPreferences.getInstance()`, there are two ways: the first is declaring it as a global variable, and loading it even in the `main` method where everything starts. By doing this you'll be able to reference it from anywhere in your code, just be careful to save the changes everytime is needed. The second is to load it everytime you need, but you'll end up using a `FutureBuilder` a lot. I don't know if any of these two options is better than the other: the first might have problems if somehow the `SharedPreferences` object gets lost, while the second requires quite more code to work.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes i load shared preferences in other screen too, in order to show user selected language. Any other solution? BTW, where this code goes? to the language screen or the UserPreferences?

Comment: I edited my answer, I tried to summarize every possibility you have.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am trying to make it globally, with the help of this link:  (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58389285/how-to-create-singleton-class-of-sharedpreferences-in-flutter/61046061#61046061)

Comment: Nice choice, I'm also pretty sure that I started using SharedPreferences with that link too.